# Could not change layout_anchor dynamically

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have this layout (There are no anchors to root CoordinatorLayout):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#F5F5F5">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/product_images_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/BlackAccentToolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/product_card_content"
            android:id="@+id/content_constraint_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/cart_fab"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/kupivip_pink_primary"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_to_cart"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior"
        app:behavior_autoHide="false"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cart_fab_top_margin_view"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/cart_fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cart_fab_left_margin_view"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/cart_fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="start|center_vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_fab"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/cart_fab_top_margin_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/favorite"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And i want to dynamically change anchor of favorite_fab corresponding to CollapsingToolbar events:

```
private void setupAppBar() {
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int state) {
                Drawable navigationIcon = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
                ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams favoriteFabLayoutParams =
                        (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) favoriteFab.getLayoutParams();

                if (state == AppBarStateListener.EXPANDED && navigationIcon != null) {
                    navigationIcon.setColorFilter(whiteColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.share).setVisible(true);

                    if (actionBar != null) actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

                    // Reposition favorite fab
                    favoriteFabLayoutParams.setAnchorId(R.id.cart_fab_top_margin_view);
                    favoriteFabLayoutParams.anchorGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                    favoriteFab.setLayoutParams(favoriteFabLayoutParams);
                    favoriteFab.show();
                }
                else if (state == AppBarStateListener.COLLAPSED && navigationIcon != null) {
                    navigationIcon.setColorFilter(toolbarIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.share).setVisible(false);

                    if (actionBar != null) {
                        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                        actionBar.setTitle(productBrandTextView.getText().toString());
                    }

                    // Reposition favorite fab
                    favoriteFabLayoutParams.setAnchorId(R.id.cart_fab_left_margin_view);
                    favoriteFabLayoutParams.anchorGravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
                    favoriteFab.setLayoutParams(favoriteFabLayoutParams);
                    favoriteFab.show();
                }
                else {
                    favoriteFab.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But during layout loading i got this error - An anchor may not be changed after CoordinatorLayout measurement begins before layout is complete.

What can be wrong with this?